# Adding an APN from the commandline

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, apn, aokp

I'm in the US for 30 days and got a SIM card from Lycamobile. For some reason adding APNs doesn't work through the GUI (I add them but they never show up in the list, even after rebooting).

Instead I added the following lines to my `/system/etc/apns-conf.xml`, just before `</apns>`

```
  <!-- BEGIN Custom APNs -->                                      
  <apn carrier="Lyca US" mcc="311" mnc="960" apn="data.lycamobile.com" type="GPRS" user="lmus" pass="plus" />
  <!-- END Custom APNs -->
```

Based on MCC and MNC data from Wikipedia and the information available online in general. I also enabled Data Roaming and International Roaming. I have rebooted my phone. I am on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running the latest AOKP nightly.

However, I still get an R in my signal tray and cannot connect to the internet. Please advise - any help would be appreciated even if it a nudge in a new direction.

Cheers,

Gausie

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if adding APN from adb shell is the right solution. But if you want to try check this [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/117125/78868).

what you basically do is change the prefered apn, or update the existing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the changes need to go into telephony.db!

Comment: Great you were able to solve it, and even share the results with us! But... what changes? And how? Mind to include some more details? Thanks in advance!