# How do I add an APN via ADB?

Tags: apn

For hardware reasons (My menu key doesn't work) I can not add an APN via settings. I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/yMvPJr6Aoq4) about using sqlite and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7869387/2711378) about using code. But I need a more convenient way to do it. I need to do it using adb.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## You Should

- **1. Be Root**
- **2. Know APN fileds such as MCC and MNC of your service provider [e.g EthioTelecom is mcc=636 mnc=01]**

## Steps

- Open adb shell

```
    $ adb shell
    $ su
```

1. Check if your carrier is listed in the default list of carriers. [] means optional

```
# content query --uri content://telephony/carriers [--where "name=''"]
```

2. If your carrier is not listed, you have to add it to the list, Add other fields as required. **NOTE** the following is for Internet, for MMS, change the fileds to what is required

```
    # content insert --uri content://telephony/carriers --bind name:s:"<Carrier Name>" --bind numeric:s:"<mcc><mnc>" --bind type:s:"default,sulp" --bind mcc:i:<mcc> --bind mnc:s:<mnc>--bind apn:s:<apn>  --bind user:s:"<User> --bind password:s:"<Password>"
```

3. Then check the listing again like Step 1
4. Note the _id, replace insert by update if this is not the first time you are setting the prefered apn

```
# content insert --uri content://telephony/carriers/preferapn --bind apn_id:i:<_id>
```

5. Try disabling and enabling your internet connection, if no change, restart your phone. if it is still not working, Keep Going
6. Change permission of settings file

```
# chmod 666 /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml
# exit
$ exit
```

7. After you exit adb shell, in your terminal/comand prompt

```
$ adb pull /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml ~/
```

8. Add The following line before the last line that says `</map>`

   `<long name="apn_id" value="<id>"/>`
9. then save it and run

```
$ adb push ~/com.android.settings_preferences.xml /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml
```

Hopefully, You should now see your apn in the access points screen in settings, and it should also work.

Comment: Thanks for this.  After doining steps 1-4 I can see the APN and it is selected.  However, when I reboot, the two records I created are no longer there.

Comment: @user2233706 It's been a while, but one issue I had was wrong mnc and mcc values. Make sure you refer to your provider's numbers.

Comment: I have a phone where the same records persist on reboot, but another phone where it does not.  The phones are supposed to be the same.

Comment: @user2233706 I'm sorry, I couldn't help buddy!

Comment: The file /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml does not exist in modern versions of android. Any idea where to apply the change listed in step 8 these days?

Comment: @Fopedush, I'm sorry I don't

Comment: The current location I found for preferred APN settings on Android Pie, on a Samsung device, was `/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/shared_prefs/preferred-full-apn.xml` Other relevant files are of interest in the same directory. (Sorry I could not comment here.)

Answer (score 1):

On a terminal (e.g. CMD prompt on Windows), type the following lines:

1. ```
   adb shell
   su
   content query --uri content://telephony/carriers --where "name='mtnirancell'"
   ```
2. ```
   content insert --uri content://telephony/carriers --bind name:s:"name" --bind numeric:s:"<mcc><mnc>" --bind type:s:"default,sulp" --bind mcc:i:<mcc> --bind mnc:s:<mnc> --bind apn:s:<name>"
   ```

   - Sample:

     ```
     content insert --uri content://telephony/carriers --bind name:s:"mtnirancell" --bind numeric:s:"43211" --bind type:s:"default,sulp" --bind mcc:i:432 --bind mnc:s:11 --bind apn:s:mtnirancell"
     ```
3. ```
   content insert --uri content://telephony/carriers/preferapn --bind apn_id:i:<_id>
   ```

   - Sample:

     ```
     content insert --uri content://telephony/carriers/preferapn --bind apn_id:i:1500
     ```
4. ```
   chmod 666 /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml
   exit   # for exit su
   exit   # for exit shell
   ```
5. ```
   adb pull /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml ~\com.android.settings_preferences.xml
   ```
6. Add the following line before the last line that says `</map>`, then save the file

   ```
   <long name="apn_id" value="1500"/>
   ```
7. ```
   adb push ~\com.android.settings_preferences.xml /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml
   ```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for  your answer, it would be wonderful if you mention which version of Android you tested with.