# How to switch between APNs using adb?

Tags: adb, shell, command-line, apn

Is there any adb or shell command available to switch between different APNs?

Comment: There is a very similar question which contains also some interesting links for you:https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117125/how-do-i-add-an-apn-via-adb